# Dynamic method signature based on prop?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that will update the field of an object like so:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b:2};
const changeObj = (field, value) => obj[field] = value;
```

This is obviously simplified, but I'm trying to make this typed properly based on the field property that is passed in. This is as close as I've gotten:

```
interface ITest {
  name: string;
  anotherProp: number;
  lastProp: IOtherInterface;
}

const obj: ITest = {name: 'test', anotherProp: 1, lastProp: {a: 'b'}};
const changeObj = (field: keyof ITest, val: ITest[keyof ITest]) => obj[field] = val;
```

Which gets me most of the way there, but technically `val` can have a value type of string, number, or IOtherInterface. Is there a way to tell the function that if I'm passing in `name` and `val` can only be a string in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work you want `changeObj` to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function:

```
const changeObj = <K extends keyof ITest>(
    field: K, val: ITest[K]
) => obj[field] = val; // okay
```

The `field` parameter is of type `K`, a type parameter that's [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof ITest`.  When you call `changeObj()`, the compiler will infer `K` based on what's passed into `field`.  Then the `val` parameter will be checked against `ITest[K]`, the type of the value you get if you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `ITest` with a key of type `K`:

```
changeObj("name", "hey") // okay
changeObj("name", 123) // error, number not a string
```

This makes it much less likely that you'll pass the wrong thing into `changeObj`.  But it doesn't completely prevent it; if `field` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), then the compiler will also accept a `val` of the analogous union type, which could cause problems:

```
changeObj(Math.random() < 0.99 ? "name" : "anotherProp", 123); // okay?
// uh oh, very good chance of a problem
```

This sort of [unsoundness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) is just part of TypeScript; the trouble situation doesn't crop up frequently enough to be addressed in the language itself.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkDyEAWt2SyIqoDewqlqCAXKgM4QzgDmA3MAL7CiHzJp0AFSiMyFKmAQBbKHUbMw7CZQRgA9rlgAFGOoAOdMAFdpAI1gcqqADYJGug3SxaYBaPxQduwJOrBi6mYAVs4iYgC8ZKhSsnQA5NCM8QA01BqujoaoAIxpdg562aTUCWbxqJyVHL7+Ykg4aixQmCGoUQA8ANKoUAAe0GAAJvSoANZQAJ7qcBjhEAB8ABQqqHAgUDZDdF1pAG4INmGiEADaXQC6wACU7QuoQcGn65tDF+2oBzY1DU0tIUsAESxKCAtKAvCTQG3AD0MIeYwQk18jSU-2CQJBYNyACYAMyw+GwPQwNImcywGKaagMJisHi-NGtDEAWQQuAAdDA1EN1NIlrcOqgAAwcgCcYtQAH5UMCZKDUHRAWpNHgYFlsTl8dc2Kg4QikVLgPrjDgHjh9rBJqgWOp1ENUIySDMafo9GYbFBpEA)